# SugarSync Integration in ios

Tags: iphone

I am trying to implement SugarSync in my application by using SugarSync sdk project, But it shows

**target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.framework.static', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform**

error whenever I am going to be run the application.

Comment: Did u succeed in integrating sugarsync?

Comment: Hey did you integrated Sugar sync ? If you got succeed with this, please help me by posting an answer here .

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search brings up a lot of [results](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework/issues/91) for that.